# SWT Access gui components

Tags: java, swt

I need to access gui components outside the class that defines them. 
My gui class contain the following code for placing object on it:

```
/**
 * Create contents of the window.
 */
protected void createContents() {
    shlCertificatesmanager = new Shell(Display.getDefault());
    shlCertificatesmanager.setSize(450, 300);
    shlCertificatesmanager.setText("CertificatesManager");
    shlCertificatesmanager.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
    MenuItemListener menuListener = new MenuItemListener(shlCertificatesmanager);

    Menu menu = new Menu(shlCertificatesmanager, SWT.BAR);
    shlCertificatesmanager.setMenuBar(menu);

    MenuItem mntmNewSubmenu = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.CASCADE);
    mntmNewSubmenu.setText("File");     

    Menu menu_1 = new Menu(mntmNewSubmenu);
    mntmNewSubmenu.setMenu(menu_1);

    MenuItem mntmOpenCertificate = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.NONE);
    mntmOpenCertificate.setText("Open Certificate");
    mntmOpenCertificate.addSelectionListener(menuListener);

    MenuItem mntmExit = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.NONE);
    mntmExit.addSelectionListener(menuListener);
    mntmExit.setText("Exit");

    MenuItem mntmHelp = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.CASCADE);        
    mntmHelp.setText("Help");

    Menu menu_2 = new Menu(mntmHelp);
    mntmHelp.setMenu(menu_2);

    MenuItem mntmAbout = new MenuItem(menu_2, SWT.NONE);
    mntmAbout.setText("About");
    mntmAbout.addSelectionListener(menuListener);

    Label lblAliasName = new Label(shlCertificatesmanager, SWT.NONE);
    lblAliasName.setText("Alias name: ");

    Label label = new Label(shlCertificatesmanager, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("___________");

}
```

Now my need is to access some of these component from an external class, in that case i need to access the two labels (lblAliasName, label) from MenuItemListener class.

There is a way  to access them? (maybe like Android with a findViewById method or similar?)

Or i need for example made them accessible from the other class in some way? (Creating a calss of gui components that will be used by both MenuItemListener class and GuiWindow class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options come to my mind:

1. If there is only one instance of your class, declare the components as `static` fields and hand them over via getter methods.
2. If there is more than one instance, declare the components as fields (this time not `static`) and create getter methods. The other class would of course have to know the instance of your class to access the methods then.

Keep in mind:

If you try to change components from a thread that is not the gui-thread, you will get an `SWTException` with value `ERROR_THREAD_INVALID_ACCESS`.

You can solve this by using:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // change/modify components here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no standard way to do this and you need to make them accessible as usual in Java.